# regular expression to match this type of string

Tags: regex, shell

I want to find the strings that share the following pattern:

The first character is + and the last character is a space. There can have more than one characters between these two characters. They can be a digit or a digit or a letter, or any other character, such as *, &, etc. But they can not be space. In other words, there only has one space for this string and is at the end position.

How to represent this pattern using regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` matches the beginning of a string, and `$` the end. You can make a character class with `[]` that matches only the things in the class, and `^` at the beginning makes it match anything not in the class, so `[^ ]` means "anything except a space". So the complete match is:

```
^\+[^ ]* $
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make sure the last character is a space?

Comment: @user288609 It's included, that's why there's a space before the `$`. If you wanted the last character to be `x` it would be `^\+[^ ]*x$`

Comment: was going to say relatively the same thing /^\+[^\s]+\s$/

Comment: Unless the result is okay with the OP, you should use a + instead of a *. The * would allow for matching a line that only contained a plus symbol and a space with no characters between.

Comment: @druciferre I know, I think that's what he asked for. It's ungrammatical, but I interpret "There can have more than one characters between these two characters" as it being optional (versus "There must be characters between these two characters")

Comment: I had read it as "one or more," but after reading it again, I'm thinking we could both be wrong and they meant "two or more." That being said... If the OP meant "zero or more" then `^\+[^ ]* $` If they meant "one or more" then `^\+[^ ]+ $` and if they meant "two or more" then `^\+[^ ]{2,} $`

Comment: @JasonBrumwell, *\s* probably shouldn't be used since it would match tab characters. The OP specifically said the line ends with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regex

```
\+[^ ]+
```

There is a space at the end of the above regex.

[See it](http://rubular.com/r/0y1dcWS7Li)